# how to add multiple class to li tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code

```
function addCardList(className, cardName) {
    console.log(className);
    var $li = $('<li class=' + className + '>');
        var $input = $('<input >', { type: 'radio', name: 'test'});
        var $label = $("<label for='test'>").text(testName);
        $li.append($input);
        $li.append($label);
        $("#card-obj").append($li);
}


for(var i=0; i<= 9; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        addCardList("borderR borderB", "AAAAA");
    }
    else {
        addCardList("borderB", "BBBBB");
    }
}
```

when the if result is true, my li page should like

```
<li class="borderR borderB">
```

but now it looks like

```
<li class="borderR" borderb><li>
```

How to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

`var $li = $('<li class=' + className + '>');`

to

`var $li = $('<li class="' + className + '">');`

Answer (score 1):

Creating the element like this gets you what you want:

```
var $li = $('<li />', { "class": className });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
var $li = $('<li>');
$li.addClass(className)
```

also using `attr`

```
$('<li>').attr("class",className)
```